# Is there a shorter way to write this jquery toggle code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle

```
    $('#checkout #button-method').on('click', function() {
        $('#button-info').removeClass('pressed').addClass('pointer');
        $('#button-method').addClass('pressed').removeClass('pointer');     
        $('#shipping-info').addClass('hide');
        $('#shipping-method').addClass('add');
    });
    $('#checkout #button-info').on('click', function() {
        $('#button-info').addClass('pressed').removeClass('pointer');
        $('#button-method').removeClass('pressed').addClass('pointer');     
        $('#shipping-info').removeClass('hide');
        $('#shipping-method').removeClass('add');
    });
```

CSS for class 'pointer' is cursor: pointer; for class 'pressed' is a background-color change; for class 'hide' is display: none; for class 'add' is display: block

There are 2 buttons (button-method and button-info). On clicking button-method, button-info is disabled, shipping-info hides, and shipping-method appears. On clicking button-info, the opposite process occurs. Is there a way to compact this code using toggleClass on two different elements?

Comment: Well I'll start by caching those elements. Since id's are unique you can simply grab the id, no need to query like `#checkout #button-method`

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer, you can update your HTML structure to allow for slightly less JS to do the same thing. Question is: is it worth the time to make your JS a line or two shorter?

Comment: Bic and Andre I like your code samples. The only issue is that the pressed buttons can still toggle. My code above makes it so that on click, there's no interaction with pressed until the other button is pressed. How would you weave that feature in, maybe using disabled?

Comment: @matenji I modified the the shortest solution in my answer. You just need to check if the button that clicked does not have the pressed class already.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATED: 4 lines of jQuery.

Ofcourse there is a better way. This is the best way to do it, from my point of view in your case.

Check code here: http://jsfiddle.net/ALsYT/10/

What I did is put them together in a "buttons" var, and since one starts hidden, that you have to do on load, I just used CSS as an example, and by using a toggle on both at the same time, I am always swapping between them.

HTML:

```
<button id="button-info" class="green">Button info</button>
<button id="button-method" class="red">Button Method</button>
<br /> <br />
<button id="shipping-info">Shipping info</button>
<button id="shipping-method">Shipping Method</button>
```

jQuery:

```
var buttons = $("#button-info, #button-method").on("click", function(){   
    $(buttons).toggleClass('red green');
    var buttons_to_toggle = $("#shipping-info, #shipping-method").toggle();
});
```

CSS:

```
.red {background-color:red}
.green {background-color:green}
#shipping-info { display:block; }
#shipping-method { display:none; }
```

Comment: Yes it is. It's just a quick example to work off, I will update the jsfiddle! Done!

Comment: Small note, you are saving a jQuery object as `buttons`, then creating a jQuery object from `buttons`. In the event handler you do not need to wrap `buttons` with `$()`.

Comment: It is true that it is overhead, works both ways in this scenario.Thanks for the note though.

Answer (score 0):

You use toggleClass(), to swap out the classes:

```
$('#button-method').on('click', function() {
    $('#button-info').toggleClass('pressed pointer');
    $(this).toggleClass('pressed pointer');     
    $('#shipping-info, #shipping-method').toggleClass('hide add');
});
$('#button-info').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('pressed pointer');
    $('#button-method').toggleClass('pressed pointer');     
    $('#shipping-info, #shipping-method').toggleClass('hide add');
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ALsYT/9/).

Your shipping-info and shipping-method classes appears to be the same. If that is the case, you can modularize them in a method so you only have the code in one place. I assumed that was an error and wrote the solution accordingly.

You can condense it further with one lining the button toggles:

```
$('#button-method').on('click', function() {
    $('#button-method, #button-info').toggleClass('pressed pointer');
    $('#shipping-info, #shipping-method').toggleClass('hide add');
});
$('#button-info').on('click', function() {
    $('#button-info, #button-method').toggleClass('pressed pointer');     
    $('#shipping-info, #shipping-method').toggleClass('hide add');
});
```

At this point the handlers become the same, so you can bind the same handler to both buttons:

```
$('#button-info, #button-method').on('click', function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('pressed')) {
        $('#button-method, #button-info').toggleClass('pressed pointer');
        $('#shipping-info, #shipping-method').toggleClass('hide add');
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution relies on one of the groups having the given classes on initial load of the page. If you need to get the classes on initially, you can utilize $.one to handle an initial button click, and within that handler, bind the subsequent click handlers.

Comment: @matenji I modified the answer based on the comment to your original post. Note, you could use disabled to kill the button so that it won't fire events, but the styling may not work in all browsers. I know that some version of IE do not allow you to style an element when it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You could use toggleClass like this:

```
function toggle(condition)
{
    $('#button-info').toggleClass('pressed', !condition).toggleClass('pointer', condition);
    $('#button-method').toggleClass('pressed', condition).toggleClass('pointer', !condition);     
    $('#shipping-info').toggleClass('hide', condition);
    $('#shipping-method').toggleClass('add', condition);
}

$('#button-method').on('click', function() {
    toggle(true);
});
$('#button-info').on('click', function() {
    toggle(false);
});
```

If you really want to compact the code, you could change your html and css so less class changes are required.